# Prevent access of users in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a site with 3 roles of users.
1.ROLE_ADMIN
2.ROLE_STUDENT
3.ROLE_PARENT

From last few days I am facing an issue.I can go to ROLE_PARENT page when i am logged in as ROLE_STUDENT.This in only happening for ROLE_STUDENT/ROLE_PARENT NOT ROLE_ADMIN

Here is my sucurity.yml

Please let me where did i go wrong.

```
security:
    encoders:
        Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\KidsKulaUsers:
            algorithm: sha512

role_hierarchy:
#        ROLE_EMPLOYEE:    [ROLE_ADVOCATES]
#        ROLE_RECRUITERS:  [ROLE_EMPLOYER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_PARENT,ROLE_STUDENT]

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:  ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login: 
            login_path: /student/login
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            check_path:    fos_user_security_check
            use_forward:                    false

        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /student/login
            #success_handler: security.logout.success_handler
        remember_me: 
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path:     /
            domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER    

access_control:
    - { path: /admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /student, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /student/find-friends, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /student/search_friends, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /student/contact, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /student/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /student/forgotpassword, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /reset-password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /student/registration, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /student/auth_registration/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /student_activation , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: /parent, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/student, roles: ROLE_STUDENT }
    - { path: ^/parent, roles: ROLE_PARENT }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at you `access_control` section:

```
....
- { path: /parent, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
- { path: ^/student, roles: ROLE_STUDENT }
- { path: ^/parent, roles: ROLE_PARENT }
```

When student navigates to `/parent` Symfony starts going over those rules. As soon as it matches the pattern it **checks the roles and quits**.

Evidently, you `/parent` route is not protected at all, so any user (students included) will be able to access it.

Remove the first rule and thing should start working as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot..i really missed that..:)